# Docker Error: No module named 'app' when trying to create prediction container to deploy flan-t5 LLM on Vertex AI

Tags: python, docker, fastapi, large-language-model

My project directory is:

```
 - predict/
   - Dockerfile
   - app/
      - main.py
   - model_output_flan_t5_base
```

Dockerfile consists of below commands:

```
# gcloud builds submit --tag europe-west4-docker.pkg.dev/argolis-rafaelsanchez-ml-dev/ml-pipelines-repo/finetuning_flan_t5_base
FROM tiangolo/uvicorn-gunicorn-fastapi:python3.8

# install dependencies
RUN python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip3 install transformers==4.25.1 sentencepiece==0.1.97 torch==1.13.0 fastapi==0.104.0

COPY ./app /app
#COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
COPY ./model-output-flan-t5-base/ /model-output-flan-t5-base/

#RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 8080

#WORKDIR /app 

# Start the app
#CMD ["gunicorn", "-b", "0.0.0.0:8080", "app.main:app","--workers","1","--timeout","180","-k","uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker"]
CMD ["uvicorn", "app.main:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "8080"]
```

My main.py is fastapi application:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, HTTPException, Request, Response
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, T5ForConditionalGeneration
#import os
#from app.main import app
#from main import app

app = FastAPI()


#@app.get("/")
#def read_root():
#    return {"message": "Welcome to the FastAPI application"}

@app.get('/health', status_code=200)
def health():
    return {"status": "healthy"}

#@app.post("/generate_summary")
#@app.get("/generate_summary")
#@app.route('/predict',methods=['GET','POST'])

@app.post('/predict')
async def predict(request: Request):
    try:
        if request.method == "POST":
            data = await request.json()
            dialogue = data.get("dialogue")
        elif request.method == "GET":
            # Handle GET request without a request body
            dialogue = ""

        if not dialogue:
            raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail="Missing 'dialogue' in the request data")

        # Load tokenizer and model
        model_id = './model-output-flan-t5-base'
        tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_id)
        model = T5ForConditionalGeneration.from_pretrained(model_id)

        # Generate summary
        generated = model.generate(**tokenizer(dialogue, return_tensors="pt", padding=True), max_new_tokens=50)
        summary = [tokenizer.decode(t, skip_special_tokens=True) for t in generated]

        return {"summary": summary}

    except Exception as e:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=500, detail=str(e))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import uvicorn
    uvicorn.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=8080)
```

I am using following command to build docker image:

```
docker build -t my-fastapi-app .
```

Command to run docker container:

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 my-fastapi-app
```

I am getting following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/uvicorn", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1157, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1078, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1434, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 783, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/uvicorn/main.py", line 404, in main
    run(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/uvicorn/main.py", line 569, in run
    server.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/uvicorn/server.py", line 60, in run
    return asyncio.run(self.serve(sockets=sockets))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/asyncio/runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "uvloop/loop.pyx", line 1517, in uvloop.loop.Loop.run_until_complete
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/uvicorn/server.py", line 67, in serve
    config.load()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/uvicorn/config.py", line 477, in load
    self.loaded_app = import_from_string(self.app)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/uvicorn/importer.py", line 24, in import_from_string
    raise exc from None
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/uvicorn/importer.py", line 21, in import_from_string
    module = importlib.import_module(module_str)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 973, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'
```

Can anyone suggest what's missing in above dockerfile and main.py fastapi app? I tried multiple way's but no luck.

Comment: The main.py app is working fine locally and I am able to get the response by using this command:

 curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{                          "dialogue": "I am Rajesh. I live in Mumbai in the state of maharashtra. I live in India"

Comment: Does the `app` folder contain a `__init__.py`?
Also, can you add a `RUN ls` command after the 2 `COPY` commands, build the docker again and update your answer with the results of the command?

Comment: Yes it contains init file.